# video streaming not working using MediaPlayerLauncher

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, video-streaming

I am developing a windows phone 8 app to stream a video file located on a server. Only authenticated users on the server can access the video file. In my app my first screen is usual username & password login page. Once user is authenticated, app streams a video stored on the server.

I am using below code to but it is not working and giving 'Sorry we can't play this file on your device'.

When i use a link of a publicly available video in my code it is able to stream. But when i use the link of the video on my server it is not able to stream. Looks like the cookies are not getting passed to the in built video player app. Any idea on how to fix this?

Below is my code.

```
            MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("https://abc.xyz.com/sites/default/files/Video/video.mp4");
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop;
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

Thanks,

Manish